# how to change template in phpbb3 forum

Tags: phpbb3

i want to change default template in phpbb3. for this where i have to made changes. i am trying to changes file inside style/subsilver2/template...but i didn't made any right .please help me ..in which file i have to made changes.i have also try in admin section in style..but not successes... if any one have clue..please help me.

Thanks
Manish

Answer (score 3):

It depends what part of the page you would like to change, since the template is a set of many HTML files with preprocessing instructions. They are located in:

[PHPBB_Folder]/styles/[Theme_Name]/template

You can find the right html file by searching for a specific part of source code copied from the live page of the forum.

**Important note**: when you're changing phpBB template files, don't forget to reset the template cache in the forum admin panel (go to Admin / Styles tab - and clear cache for what you changed, Template, Theme, or Imageset.

I hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for reply...

suppose i want to change whole page. then i have to change first header part. so i made changes from \styles\subsilver2\template\overall_header.html..but no changes occur in front. suppose i have to made changes in body section then i want to update index_body.html file. but it also useless.

Please give me idea how to change over all page like header,footer, and body part too.

Thanks
Manish

Comment: That's correct, you need to change a lot of files if you need to make many changes - best is to do them one by one, checking the HTML source of the part that you want to change, and then searching for it in the HTMl files of the template.

Important note: when you're changing phpBB template files, don't forget to reset the template cache in the forum admin panel (go to Admin / Styles tab - and clear cache for what you changed, Template, Theme, or Imageset (I also added this to the answer).